# Read SFTP credentials from separate file using WinSCP and Windows batch file

Tags: batch-file, scripting, sftp, winscp

I am writing a batch script to connect to SFTP server having private key and passphrase.

I have developed a script using WinSCP. But if we use WinSCP we need to hard code passphrase which I feel is not the secured way to implement.

Is there any way to store passphrase in a file and pass that file name as argument or can we create a batch script to achieve this without using WinSCP?

Below is the script that I have implemented using WinSCP.

Batch file:

```
winscp.com /script=script.txt
```

Below is the content that I have included in `script.txt` file:

```
option echo off 
option batch on 
option confirm off 
open sftp://username:password@hostname -privatekey="filename" -passphrase "passphrase"
put "filename" /
exit
```

Answer (score 0):

Quoting "Scripting" section of WinSCP article [Protecting credentials used for automation](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/guide_protecting_credentials_for_automation):

> In [script](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/scripting), you can replace actual credentials with reference to environment variables. You can then call WinSCP from a batch file that sets these variables. The batch file itself then serves as a "configuration file".
>
> For example, following script (`example.txt`):
>
> ```
> open sftp://%USERNAME%:%PASSWORD%@example.com
> ...
> ```
>
> can be called from this batch file ("configuration file"):
>
> ```
> @echo off
> set USERNAME=martin
> set PASSWORD=mypassword
> winscp.com /script=example.txt
> ```

*(though you better read the [whole article](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/guide_protecting_credentials_for_automation))*